# Setting Up a Reusable Test Render Function in redux toolkit v2

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux, redux-toolkit

Below function works well as a redux toolkit test render wrapper before the redux toolkit v2. but with the release of v2 **EmptyObject** type is missing (so it's required all the reducers to be defined inside preloaded state) from redux state and also **PreloadedState** type is not exported from @reduxjs/toolkit package. Is there any updated solution to use with redux toolkit v2 ?

```
import type { AppState, AppStore } from "@/store";
import uiReducer from "@/store/slices/ui-slice";
import type { PreloadedState } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type { RenderOptions } from "@testing-library/react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

interface ExtendedRenderOptions extends Omit<RenderOptions, "queries"> {
  preloadedState?: PreloadedState<AppState>;
  store?: AppStore;
}

export function renderWithProviders(
  ui: React.ReactElement,
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        ui: uiReducer,
      },
      preloadedState,
    }),
    ...renderOptions
  }: ExtendedRenderOptions = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>): React.JSX.Element {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
  }

  return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`preloadedState` can be anything that is a valid input to your root reducer, so in your case it would be

```
{
  ui: Parameters<typeof uiReducer>[0]
}
```